# jquery loop function forever?

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I am using the following jquery script which changes the colour of a checkbox to red when a user has clicked on it, and to black when it is unchecked.

The checkbox starts of black as it is unchecked, then when a user clicks in the checkbox it changes the background of the checkbox to red.

My problem is this, if a user checks the checkbox the first time this goes from black to red, then if they uncheck the checkbox it goes back to black. However for whatever reason if they want to re-check the checkbox it does not go back to red?

Is there a way in which I can make this function run on a loop? thanks in advance...

```
<script>
    $(this).children("input").attr("checked");
    $(document).ready(function() {

// assuming all checkboxes are unchecked at first
$("span[class='checkbox']").addClass("unchecked");

    $(".checkbox").click(function(){
        if($(this).children("input").attr("checked")){
            // uncheck
            $(this).children("input").attr({checked: ""});
            $(this).removeClass("checked");
            $(this).addClass("unchecked");
        }else{
            // check
            $(this).children("input").attr({checked: "checked"});
            $(this).removeClass("unchecked");
            $(this).addClass("checked");
        }


    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: `$(this).children("input").attr("checked");` this cause the error...

Comment: @BhojendraNepal: That code doesn't actually do anything other than reading the attribute and then ignoring it. If the code block isn't below the elements, then it doesn't even do that, as the elements doesn't exist yet.

Comment: I mean to the code in very first line right after `<script>` in the OP question..

Answer (score 0):

Add one flag here..so when user do first action of tick and untick it will get true and next time user will not allow to change color based on flag status...i have given only example..you can modify result as per your requirement.

```
$("span[class='checkbox']").addClass("unchecked");
var isCheckboxTicked = false;
    $(".checkbox").click(function(){
        if($(this).children("input").attr("checked")){
            // uncheck
            $(this).children("input").attr({checked: ""});
            $(this).removeClass("checked");
            $(this).addClass("unchecked");
            isCheckboxTicked = true;
        }else{
            // check
            if(!isCheckboxTicked){
             $(this).children("input").attr({checked: "checked"});
             $(this).removeClass("unchecked");
             $(this).addClass("checked");
            }
        }


    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Trying to catch the click on the containing element to control the checkbox is problematic. It won't work properly if the user clicks the actual checkbox and not outside it. You would have to catch the click on the checkbox also, and treat that differently, and even then it doesn't work for other ways of changing the checkbox state than clicking on it.

Instead, catch the `change` event on the checkbox, and change the class on the containing element according to the state of the checkbox:

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {

  $("span.checkbox").addClass("unchecked");

  $(".checkbox input").change(function(e){
    var container = $(this).closest('.checkbox');
    var checked = $(this).prop("checked");
    container.toggleClass("unchecked", !checked);
    container.toggleClass("checked", checked);
  });

});

</script>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/89rx0mnc/

If you also want to allow clicking on the parent element to change the checkbox, you can catch that click and trigger the event on the checkbox:

```
$(".checkbox").click(function(e){
  if(e.target == this) {
    $(this).children("input").click();
  }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/89rx0mnc/1/